# REST APIs and network delays

Tags: java, performance, rest, amazon-web-services, profiling

We use a web application built with HTML5, (Angular) JS that communicates with REST APIs on the backend.
The backend is developed using Java (Jersey) with a H2 database and is deployed on a tomcat application server that is hosted at Amazon.

I timed execution times of the Rest services using my audit logging (AOP) and noticed a big difference in execution time between the time spent in the service and the execution time of the end to end call.

We store a lot of workflows that each contain a document (JSON) with a total file size of about 90Kb that is fetched every time (so if we get 50 workflows, 50 x documents of 90Kb size are returned over the network).

Here are my experiences:

Retrieving a workflow with pagination size 1:

From the server logs:

```
GET Request: Get all workflows with range [items=1-2]
[PROFILING] WorkflowRestService method GetAll took [26] millis to complete

GET Request: Get all workflows with range [items=2-3]
[PROFILING] WorkflowRestService method GetAll took [28] millis to complete

GET Request: Get all workflows with range [items=3-4]
[PROFILING] WorkflowRestService method GetAll took [26] millis to complete

GET Request: Get all workflows with range [items=4-5]
[PROFILING] WorkflowRestService method GetAll took [25] millis to complete

GET Request: Get all workflows with range [items=5-6]
[PROFILING] WorkflowRestService method GetAll took [26] millis to complete
```

EndToEnd :

```
Time to retrieve items [1-2] took 299 millis
Time to retrieve items [2-3] took 388 millis
Time to retrieve items [3-4] took 406 millis
Time to retrieve items [4-5] took 477 millis
Time to retrieve items [5-6] took 370 millis
```

Retrieving a workflow with pagination size 50:

From the server logs:

```
GET Request: Get all workflows with range [items=1-50]
[PROFILING] WorkflowRestService method GetAll took [108] millis to complete

GET Request: Get all workflows with range [items=51-100] 
[PROFILING] WorkflowRestService method GetAll took [106] millis to complete

GET Request: Get all workflows with range [items=101-150]
[PROFILING] WorkflowRestService method GetAll took [109] millis to complete

GET Request: Get all workflows with range [items=151-200]
[PROFILING] WorkflowRestService method GetAll took [112] millis to complete

GET Request: Get all workflows with range [items=201-250]
[PROFILING] WorkflowRestService method GetAll took [106] millis to complete
```

EndToEnd :

```
Time to retrieve items [1-50] took 1777 millis
Time to retrieve items [51-100] took 753 millis
Time to retrieve items [101-150] took 1143 millis
Time to retrieve items [151-200] took 1709 millis
Time to retrieve items [201-250] took 1703 millis
```

So I see a linear evalution in difference between server execution time on the server and endToEnd (every time x10/20).

Is there anyone with a good idea on how I could further elaborate?
Maybe it is the file size that has to be pushed over the network and gzipping it could provide me time benefit?
Maybe some other ideas or experiences?
Maybe some tools I could use to further investigate what takes so much time?

Comment: Have you thought of minifying your JSON responses back from the server?  removing spaces and so on to reduce down the size, secondly enabling output compressions may make sense, but first i would first benchmark the alternatives and determine the best cause of action.

Comment: Are you asking why having to process / serve a larger data set, then transmit it over the network takes more time? Where you'll be able to improve performance is highly situational.